# Ue4 make 2d game ,two instance of Player show at the map

Tags: unreal-engine4

I use the Unreal Engine 4.27,and pure blueprint implement the game.
I was make a 2D game ,i have been make a simple map,and custom  a gameMode,Character and my character controller. I am sure the gameMode bindings my custom character and it's controller.
And there a singleton instance of my custom player ,and no Player Starter,but there are two character in my map,one is run by my input key,and the other is just like a picture.\

I want to know why is this happening?
And how to deal with it?
Your advices are greatly appreciated. Thank you.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may restart the Ue editor first，sometimes the ue rendering system will encounter some problem.
If not,check the auto possess player of your character blueprint has been set,sometimes for a single player game, it should be set as player 0

Comment: Can you explain the principle to me？Or the thinking process? I hava solve the problem,but i don't know why...